# My GUI repeat many times and can't input or click in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a problem.
I coding JAVA MVC in Netbeans 
When I run it, JFrame Show multiple windows and can't input or click

[Image while run code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ljbT.jpg)

this is my code 
View:

```
public StudentView() {
    initComponents();

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new StudentView().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public StudentController(Student model, StudentView view){
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;
}

public void initController() {
    view.getBtnOKsing().addActionListener(e -> getText());
}
public void getData(){
    dataStd = model.getStudentNo();
    dataPass = model.getPass(); 
}
public void getText(){
    stdNo = view.getTextstd();
    pass = view.getTextpass();
    //singin();
}
```

in my program don't have loop.

Comment: let me see your full class of StudentView

Comment: @MorganDenis [this is link drive to my code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sopFV5xJl6sEct3Dd6bsznlfuKZxjPil?usp=sharing)

Comment: on the StudeView class constructor remove this line 'frame.setVisible(true);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
new StudentView().setVisible(true);
```

to

```
setVisible(true).
```